# JQuery sidebar sildes after pressing menu button

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use the animate function in JQuery for a sidebar menu to appear from left (slide) after pressing a menu button. Although i searched the database of stack overflow i still couldn't make it work. So i need to make it slide from left to right with 1 sec delay, after pressing the menu button.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sok-app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="background-2" >
<button id="menu_button"> <a href="#menu">
  &#9776; </a> </button>
   <div class="sidebar" style="width:130px display:none">

  <button id="your-best-ap" >Your app</button>
  <button id="team-history-conta" >Team</button>
  <button id="team-history-conta" >History</button>
  <button id="team-history-conta" >Contact</button>
  <button id="suggest-to-a-friend" >Suggest to a friend</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#menu_button").click(function(){
        $(".sidebar").animate({left: '412px'});   //animate margin to create slide from left animation  
    }, 1000);                                     //duration of animation, in milliseconds
 });
</script> 


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting **duration** to `click` event, not animate. And this code won't be able to run `alert`, because there is formatting error which I mentioned at the first sentence.

Change it like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#menu_button").on("click",function(){
        $(".sidebar").animate({left: '412px', width:'toggle'},1000); 
       // duration after animate properties 
    });                                   
 });
```

[Result](https://jsfiddle.net/pvvfjyon/3/)

Hope helps,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although it moves further (from the point of 412px width and to the right), it 's working whenever I press the button.

Comment: Then make it -412 :) @SokratisV